# Currency Conversion in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am working through a list of transactions, and I am looking to identify transactions over a specific amount which were successful the first time. I have done this and it works fine:

```
select * from transactions
where (user_id, created_date) in 
(
select user_id, min(created_date) from transactions AS T
where amount > 10 
group by user_id
)
AND state = 'COMPLETED';
```

The problem I am now facing is that the transactions are all in different currencies, and I need them to be USD equivalent. I have a transaction table, and I have an FX rate table so I imagine I need to join the two together, but I can't work out how to integrate the conversion. The tables look a little something like this, I am unsure how to import a table directly:

```
Transactions: 
Currency Amount

GBP      3738
AED      588
BTC      1264
EUR      66

FX Rates:

Base Curency Curency Rate

EUR          AED     0.239335579
GBP          HKD     0.103876887
USD          NOK     0.129818755
```

and I have this for EUR, GBP, and USD so I need to take the transactions, locate the correct rate and divide. I just don't know where to begin other than joining the two tables together.

Comment: I'd tackle your problem with a case statement. Have a look here: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-case/ ... Re: Joining tables in order to achieve this, please list the structure of your tables and provide some example data. The more info you provide here, the better an answer you'll get!

Comment: You might consider looking at correlated subqueries. You can use a subquery even in the select statement that might allow you to do your conversions as well. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery

Comment: @BarryPiccinni Thank you for your comment. So I understand what you linked, and I am thinking about how I might use it. The only problem is that there are easily 30+ currency rates, and so in theory I guess I could use the searched case expression for everyone case to create a new transaction column. But this seems a very long-winded approach so I must be missing a simpler way that you mean I could use it?

Comment: @Dean What concerns me about this approach is that it needs to be run everytime, and the page you sent me seems to think this makes it slow. I have 176,000 transactions to look at. When its stated that this would be slow, does it mean a few hours, or a few minutes? Thanks!

Comment: @Jabanew If you provide an example of that tables you intent to use, someone will guide you to the best way. At the moment, nobody can see how any of your suggested data links to the other tables you mentioned, so it's not possible to give a comprehensive answer.

Comment: @BarryPiccinni Thank you for your help, I have attempted to update my question with the relevent tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you have two tables:

1. Transactions
2. FX

[image]

You can then run this to convert everything into euros:

```
SELECT      #transactions.*,
            #transactions.[Value] * #fx.Rate [Value in Euros]
FROM        #transactions
INNER JOIN  #fx
ON          #transactions.Currency = #fx.[Currency - sell]
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response, and I think i managed to tweak this and my data to get it to work. However, I have now encountered an issue. When the transaction is already in USD, the query just skips over it so in my output I am missing X amount of USD transactions. So I think I need to write some kind of an 'if' statment to say "If USD, leave. Else do 'the code above'..."

Comment: An “if - else” would be doable but why don’t you just insert another row into your FX table with the enchange rate of USD -> USD = 1.00? Then you can keep the same logic.

Comment: Yeah this is exactly what i ended up doing haha. Why make things harder for myself! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I'm making assumptions about what data you have and the names but you can do something like this.

```
 SELECT *, T.amount * CC.CoversionRate AS UsdPrice
 FROM Transactions AS T
 JOIN CurrencyConvert AS CC on T.CurrencyID = CC.CurrencyID
```